# How to set tab index > 0 in TabNavigator at initilize, flex

Tags: apache-flex

How to set tab index > 0 in TabNavigator control at initilize, flex

Answer (score 2):

There is a property selectedIndex which you can set. Look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/ViewStack.html#selectedIndex)

Comment: i have tried it that way
tn.selectedIndex =2;
but it is not working 

but after creating the TabNavigation if i execute 
tn.selectedIndex =2; this line in a button click event it will work.

so i have decided to call this Creation complete event on TabNavigation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Flex 3, extend the TabNavigator and make a component with the following. After that selectedIndex works.

```
<mx:TabNavigator xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
override protected function commitSelectedIndex(newIndex:int):void
{
super.commitSelectedIndex(newIndex);
tabBar.selectedIndex = newIndex;
}
]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```